# Identificação de regiões google maps - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, google, maps

Possuo uma lista de latitudes e longitudes e eu gostaria de descobrir em qual região do pais tal latitude/longitude pertence.

Comment: Poste o que você já fez.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize *Reverse Geocoding*. Exemplo:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false
```

Retorna um JSON com vários elementos, inclusive:

```
formatted_address" : "277 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA", [...]
```